# About Consent for publishing in conference

Tags: publications, ethics, paper-submission, conference, research-misconduct

I'm a first year PhD student. I never have any record of publication or conference paper before.

In my PhD, I worked as a coauthor for the post doctoral fellow's paper. My post doc work 24x7 sundays and Saturdays holidays but I am not like that. One sunday she asked to come for work, me and another phd student clearly refused it. After that she didn't ask us anything to do for the research. After the experiment work finished, she did all the analysis Without our knowledge. Then, supervisor and postdoc are presenting it in various conferences. For one conference, a day before the conference @5PM, they send me a presentation out of nowhere and they are going to present where my name was there but I am completely unaware of this and I didn't even reply to that email yet they presented it.

Also prof and postdoc are now presenting it in international conference but I was never informed about it. This time I never knew whether my name was there or not ? My fellow PhD student who is also another coauthor informed me about this. He was also mad at this time, because he asked them for dates to conduct his research but they told him that they are presenting that postdoc work in a conference on that dates So they are unavailable. We never knew about abstract submission and all the process happened.

Now, they are planning to submit the manuscript for a journal and informed us to approve the consent.  I don't know much about academic conducts and rules. Can my collaborators present this work in conferences without my knowledge and consent?

Comment: Struggled to understand what exactly your concern is/are. Question might do well with clarity.

Comment: When you edited... *Can they present the works in the conference without my knowledge and consent* ... are you concerned about the journal manuscript or previous conferences?

Comment: Conference ? For Journal manuscript, I need to approve through email. So they told me about it. But for conference I have no idea what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

> *now presenting it in international conference ... I never knew whether my name was there or not*

Conferences would normally have proceedings or even anthology. You can check if your names are listed.

> *informed us to approve the consent.*

Informing you and requesting consent are in order. I'll say approach from the positive side and use that as a leeway to get involved, learn about academic publishing and also get 'clarity'.
PS: kindly let us know of this consent is for authorship or acknowledgment

A quick add-on regarding authorship, since you didn't indicate if this *approve the consent* include given a copy of the manuscript to peruse, kindly use the opportunity to *get involved* in the *Writing - Review & Editing)*.
See [CRediT author statement](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/credit-author-statement)

> *One sunday she asked to come for work, me and another phd student clearly refused it. After that she **didn't ask us anything to do for the research**.*

It is within your right to decline working on Sun, especially if it's a service day for you.
However, you ought to have meaningfully engaged afterwards and not just now 'waking up' after staying aloof.
As a PhD student, taking initiative and being proactive are great assets!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you expected your professor and the post doc to ask for your permission to present your joint work.

I had exactly the same feelings with you when I first started working on research, but I eventually got used to it.
I used to find out that my prof. presented my work at some conference/lab meeting from the internet, and he would never mention anything. From some uploaded pdfs I even found out that he was using the slides from my presentation for my thesis without even mentioning my name sometimes (this still annoys me).

On the other hand after this (and after I left the lab) I started also presenting our joint work without asking permission or informing (although I always mention the collaborators in each work).

You can have a brief discussion with your prof that you would like to get informed in which conferences they present. You can make the discussion non-confrontational but formulate it as being interested to see in which conferences your work fits in, and probably ask whether you can join them in one of them.